# What is $D$ or $D$-with-a-slash-through-it in the Standard Model equation(s)?

Tags: gauge-theory, differentiation, notation, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

In the mathematical formulation of the Standard Model, which I do not understand yet, there is a capital letter $D$ or $D$-with-a-slash-through-it that I can't find an explanation for.

Flip Tanedo (a popular 'quantum blogger') just said offhand that it has something to do with bosonic gauge fields.

I am curious because I see 'shortened' versions of the Standard Model on T-shirts and mugs and such.   They're becoming very popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notation is known as the Feynman or Dirac [slash notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_slash_notation). The symbol under the slash must be a Lorentz four-vector, and the slash implies that this four-vector should be contracted with the four-vector of [Dirac gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices):
$$
 {A\!\!\!/} = \gamma ^{\mu }A_{\mu }. 
$$
(This identity uses the Einstein summation convention, so repeated indices are summed over.)

The $D$ that you saw under the slash sign is a covariant derivative:
$$
D_\mu = \partial_\mu + A_\mu, 
$$
where $\partial_\mu$ is a partial derivative and $A_\mu$ is the (electromagnetic) vector potential. This combination is commonly seen in the [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) under an electromagnetic field, as well as all the field theories built on top of it.